# How to visit a page several times in a row with PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Is it possible to open page, do my things and close it. And after a timeout visit it once again to see the content changes (page has many js functions). Trying to open the page twice in a row makes PhantomJS behave unpredictable. What is the solution then?

Comment: page.open(url, function(status){   
   
   page.evaluate(function() {
    
    //Doing some actions 1 
    
   });
   
     
   setTimeout(function(){   
   
   
    page.evaluate(function(){
    
     button = document.getElementById("button");
     button.click();     
     
    
    });
        
    page.render("2.png");
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.write(result, page.content, 'w');
    console.log('Finished');
    phantom.exit(); 
   }, timeout);
});

Comment: Your updated code has nothing to do with the title, your question and my answer. If you still have a problem you should ask a new question. I rolled back your edit. You code also has only one `page.open` statement.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that, i'am a mixed-up today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most the execution in PhantomJS is asynchronous, so you have to open a page only after the first page load was completed:

```
page.open(url, function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // do something
        page.open(url, function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                // do something
                phantom.exit();
            }, 5000); // 5 seconds
        });
    }, 5000); // 5 seconds
});
```

or even better using recursion:

```
var i = 0;
function run(){
    if (i > 100) { // stop execution at some point
        phantom.exit();
    }
    page.open(url, function(){
        // do what you have to do
        setTimeout(run, 5000); // run again in 5 seconds
    });
}
run();
```

Comment: It' doesn't actually work. I have two steps in my program. First i'am submitting form on the page, and then i'am sending raw post request. I tried setTimeout variants, but second page.open() never starts. So i dunno what to do with that.

Comment: That's too bad. As I said before, that issue has nothing to do with this question. You can ask a new question and when that new question is solved, you can apply the techniques I laid out in this answer.