# How to open few pages in sequence (PhantomJS)?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

As i see, you can't just open few pages with page.open() in one phantomjs script. Because they began to work simultaneously. I tried variations with seTtimeout() but they didn't work. So what i need is to open first page, do some actions, then close it. After that i need to open another page. How can i achieve that?

```
var url = 'url-address-';
var referrer = '-url-address-/path';
page.customHeaders={'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa(login+":"+password), 'Referer': referrer};

page.open(url, function(status){
    if(status === 'fail')
    {
        console.log('Status: ' + status);
        phantom.exit();
    }

    console.log('Status: ' + status);
    page.render("1.png");

    page.evaluate(function() {
        var form = document.forms[0];   
        form.data1.value = 'mydata_name';
        form.data2.value = 'mydata_surname';
        form.submit();
    }); 

    setTimeout(function(){
        var url = 'post-url-address';
        var referrer = '-url-address-/refpath';
        page.customHeaders={'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa(login+":"+password), 'Referer': referrer};   
        body = 'submit-url=mydata_to_submit';
        page.open(url, 'POST', body, function (status) {
            //
            // Here goes the error 
            // unable to load url: "post-url-address"
            //  error code: 5, description: Operation canceled
            //
            //
            //setTimeout(function(){}, 5000)
            console.log('Status: ' + status);
        }); 

        page.render("2.png");
        var fs = require('fs');
        fs.write(result, page.content, 'w');
        console.log('Finished');
        phantom.exit();

    }, timeout);
});
```

So its all goin well untill i open page to post data. Dunno why its happening. Tried to change timeout to 20-30 sec - issue remains. It's not obivusly why is that happening, isn't it?

Comment: Please provide a full script that reproduces the problem, because this should work. Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: okay, ill register error messages now

Comment: It loads first page properly, then when it comes to post data, script says 5, description: Operation canceled. I post some part of the code now

Comment: What version of PhantomJS do you use and is it an https URL?

Comment: Its latests (2.0.0) version of PhantomJS and its http url i'am trying to access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You're exiting too early.*

You break off from the control flow after you open the second page. You have to move the file writing and the exit into the `page.open()` callback. The error probably happens because PhantomJS is currently trying to download the page and at the same time trying to exit the execution. That is why the second page load is cancelled.

Use:

```
// second page.open ...
page.open(url, 'POST', body, function (status) {
    console.log('Status: ' + status);
    page.render("2.png");
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.write(result, page.content, 'w');
    console.log('Finished');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Please look again at the previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525123/how-to-visit-a-page-several-times-in-a-row-with-phantomjs